# US Int with Dead Keys

Tags: keyboard

I have always used English (US int w Dead Keys).  I just installed Ubuntu 23.10 and keyboard US int w Dead keys like I always did in the past, and it shows up and I can select it, but I can not type any of the accented characters.  The try Ubuntu USB drive works fine, but after the install, the laptop just will not type international characters.  Thanks for any help - Ed

Comment: Can you please create an extra user for test purposes and check if the issue is present with that user too.

Comment: My Goodness - that worked.  The NEW user log in works perfectly but my normal user login will not type any accented characters.  What should I do now?   Can / Should I delete my first user name, change the new one to the old one, or what.  THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Then we know that the issue is caused by something in `$HOME`. The first thing I would try is to delete (or rename) the `~/.cache` directory.

Comment: I renamed .cache to .cache.ori - logged off and back on again.  Still can´t type accented characters,  looks like everything else still works, i.e. chromian tabs still there.  Looks like a new .cache directory got created.  I think you are on the right track.  I wish I understood more of the behind the scene stuff.  THANK you.

Comment: I just noticed something.  When I look at the keyboard layout and press, for example, the shift or cntl keys, I see those keys highlighted on the keyboard layout.  BUT, when I press the right alt key, the one I normally use to select the accented characters, it does NOT highlight --- SO - I changed the Álternet Char Set' key FROM the right ALT to the LEFT ALT, and that works,  So, now I am thinking mthe right ALT key on my laptop broke or got dirt under it or something. i.e it is a mechanical problem, not a software problem.  I will keep you posted as I learn more, but THANK for your patience.

Comment: But now I am confused as to why setting up a new user works.  I am confused.

Comment: I found a temporary fix.  I changed the Ált Character Key' FROM the right ALT key to the right CNTL key.  This seems to work.  I just have to retrain myself that when I am on this laptop, I have to use the RIGHT cntl key.  All other lapts use the right ALT key to get the accented chacacters.  i dont understand it, but at least I am able to work.

Comment: I don´t know if this is important, but I just noticed in the .cache directory where the ALT key does NOT work, there are a bunch of file with names like ksycoca5_en_DMQz9f08MeurlAGNAOtsXVVcyu8=  but there are no such files in the .cache directory of the new user I created. I no idea what those files are.

Comment: This is probably an upgrade, and not a fresh install? You could try resetting all things gnome (`dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`). Beware, that will revert everything to factory default settings.